# Configure Jackson to use SNAKE_CASE "globally" in Spring Boot 2.0.0.M1

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, kotlin, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring Boot `2.0.0.M1` (hence Spring `5.0.0.RC1`). I'm trying to configure it to make use of `PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.SNAKE_CASE` but I doesn't work so far.

I've tried:

1. The `application.yml` file with:

   ```
   spring:
     jackson:
       property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE
   ```
2. Configuring a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` bean:

   ```
   @Bean
   @Primary
   open fun jacksonBuilder(): Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder {
     val jacksonMapperBuilder = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
         .failOnUnknownProperties(false)
         .modules(JavaTimeModule(), KotlinModule())
         .propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.SNAKE_CASE)
     logger.info { "Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder configured successfully..." }
     return jacksonMapperBuilder
   }
   ```
3. Configuring an `ObjectMapper` bean:

   ```
   @Bean
   @Primary
   open fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
     val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
     objectMapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
     objectMapper.registerModule(KotlinModule())
     objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.SNAKE_CASE)
     logger.info { "ObjectMapper configured successfully..." }
     return objectMapper
   }
   ```

The only way I've found to make it work it by annotating every single class with `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy::class)`...but that's not a solution for my case.

Any other options?

---

This is the `dependencies` "section" in my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
dependencies {
  compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
  compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
  compile("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.4.4")
  //compile("io.projectreactor:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive")
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
  compile(kotlin("stdlib"))

  testCompile("io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-test")
  testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This was indeed fixed on `M3`; if you need the `SnakeCaseStrategy.SNAKE_CASE` the setting(s) in `application.yml` are enough.

Comment: Option 1 is working fine for me if I set up a simple project with Spring boot and `spring-boot-starter-web` with version 2.0.0.M1. Are you sure you're not creating a Jackson `ObjectMapper` bean somewhere by yourself?

Comment: Looks like a "problem" with the WebFlux module; it's targeting the `M3`...I can wait :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [Web-Flux module documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/web.html#web-reactive-http-body) states:

> The `spring-core` module provides reactive `Encoder` and `Decoder` contracts that enable the serialization of a `Flux` of bytes to and from typed objects.

Apparently the automatically configured `ObjectMapper` by `JacksonAutoConfiguration` won't be picked up by the [`WebFluxAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebFluxAutoConfiguration.java) and [`WebFluxConfigurationSupport`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/config/WebFluxConfigurationSupport.java) when configuring an instance of [`Jackson2JsonEncoder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/codec/json/Jackson2JsonEncoder.java). This issue already reported in [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9166) and currently planned for `M3` milestone.

Comment: Indeed; it looks like it won't be fixed until `M3`...thanks!

Comment: ...and it's actually fixed on `M3` (and hopefully on-wards).